# ReactNative - "expo start" works with tsx file which is not conforming typescript grammar

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I've just started reactive native.
I created a project with "expo init" with "blank (TypeScript)" option selected.

Created a component called GoalItem.tsx as below,

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const GoalItem = props => (
  <View>
    <Text>{props.title}</Text>
  </View>
)

export default GoalItem
```

It's just a javascript code in tsx file.
When typed `tsc` in the terminal, I get errors related to typescript grammar which is expected.

When I typed `expo start`, it just works well without any warnings nor errors.

Questions:
How do we make `expo start` to check typescript grammar first?

This is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also been wondering about this.
The only hacky solution i've found is to change the script to manually compile typescript first and then run expo. I don't believe it works with every refresh of the code but at least you have the reassurance that if you restart "start" then you get typescript compilation.

In `package.json` this is what i've changed

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "yarn tsc && expo start" <-- change is here
    [...]
}
```

This will also read a valid `tsconfig.json` if present.

Keep in mind you need to execute the "start" script for this to work e.g. "yarn start" and not just "expo start".